# Logical structure of a postgres heap table?

Tags: database, postgresql, relational-database

I am trying to understand postgres from the inside out and here is what I have learnt till now.

- Each database has its own subdirectory inside $PG_DATA/base ($PG_DATA being the environment variable pointing to the postgres installation dir)
  This can be verified by issuing the query `SELECT datname, oid FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'db_name';`. And then we can physically go inside the directory base to very this.There is no logical structure to a database since it just a directory inside which the files are present.
- Within this directory tables are organised as single files with oids as well.This oid can be obtained by the following query `SELECT relname, oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'table_name';`.These files can grow till 1 GB and from there on it can be split based on a parameter, usually this split occurs to overcome filesystem limitations and it is tunable.

All is good till this point, but I am unable to understand how tuples are organized inside tables.From what I see tuples are basically rows which expand using TOAST if they don't fit inside of a page which is basically the storage unit of 8KB.

Postgres uses the concept of heap tables, more specifically said unordered heaps for storing tuples quoted from [here](http://facility9.com/2011/03/postgresql-row-storage-fundamentals/).I am aware of the concept of min/max heap which are basically modified form of binary trees, but unable to find any reference/material related to unordered heap data structure.

My C knowledge is a little bit rusty so looking at the actual source code did not help me much.Any help in understanding the unordered heap structure i.e how tuples are organized as tables will be very much appreciated.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-page-layout.html

Comment: I am confused,is a table simply a collection of pages then ?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely it.

Comment: Oh..missed that point in the documentation..the name unordered heaps mislead me..is this question adding any value then..should I be deleting it?